# How to calculate the physical area of a polygon in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

As part of an application I am working on, I am trying to determine the physical area of a polygon that the user has drawn on the screen.

I am calculating the area of the polygon in points using the method detailed here:

http://www.mathopenref.com/coordpolygonarea.html

However I am a little bit stuck on how to get from the area in points to the physical area, like square inches. I believe the DPI of the device I am testing on (iPad Pro, 9.7") is 264. Is the equation to get the area in inches really as simple as pointsArea / (dpi * dpi)? This doesn't seem to yield the correct result by a large margin without just throwing several magic numbers into the mix.

The code I am using to calculate the points area is as follows:

```
- (double)calculatePointsArea {
    double localPointsArea = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < points.count; x++) {
        if (x + 1 < points.count) {
            localPointsArea += (points[x].imagePoint.x * points[x + 1].imagePoint.y) - (points[x].imagePoint.y * points[x + 1].imagePoint.x);
        }
        else {
            localPointsArea += (points[x].imagePoint.x * points[0].imagePoint.y) - (points[x].imagePoint.y * points[0].imagePoint.x);
        }
    }
    localPointsArea = localPointsArea / 2;
    return fabs(localPointsArea);
}
```

The code I am using to play with the area calculations is as follows:

```
pointsArea = [self calculatePointsArea];
long dpi = [TSTDPIManager deviceDPI]; //this is a class to manage the dpi values for various devices. Right now it is set to return 264 for my device, which I believe is correct.

double physicalAreaUsingPoints = ((pointsArea) / (dpi * dpi));
physicalAreaUsingPoints = physicalAreaUsingPoints * (7.2); 7.2 is completely arbitrary, but seems to yield the correct result on my device and the simulator.
```

The arbitrary magic number is sending me a very strong signal that I am miscalculating things somewhere, but I am having a hard time figuring out what it is. Apologies in advance if it something extremely obvious. I have been googling and poking this for a few days and I don't feel like I am making a lot of progress on it.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to guess, but I assume you debugged `calculatePointsArea`? I suspect you're operating on points instead of pixels. Use `[UIScreen scale]` to get a scale factor for iPad Pro's Retina screen.

Other than that, the typical way I debug algorithms is to use a lot of temporary variables, and print them out everywhere. Then I provide very simple test data and make sure all steps of the algorithm yield expected results. So make `(1,1)--(10,1)--(10,10)--(1,10)` rectangle and make sure you're getting `81` as size.

Comment: I have verified calculatePointsArea with a few test sets. I plugged in what you suggested and it does return 81 as the size. You are correct in your statement that I am working with points instead of pixels, and I believe my problem is happening trying to go from points to physical size.

I have played with using the scale, but still would not get expected results. Are you suggesting the correct formula would be (pointsArea * scale) / (dpi^2)?

Comment: Draw yourself a 3x3 rectangle and try to scale it by 2. Imagine that what you operate on are points, and you want to get pixels.

`scale` scales from points to pixels. **Example**: 3px3p point rectangle (9p^2) scaled `x 2` will be 6x6 (36p^2), not 3x6 (p^2)

You should be able to figure the formula from this.

Comment: Thanks again. I appreciate the help. I'm not sure how I overlooked that one. I am currently using the formula (pointsArea * scale^2)/(dpi^2) and this seems to be yielding more consistent results. The results I am getting seem to be short about 75-77% consistently. This seems to coincide with the aspect ratio, and multiplying by 1.75-1.77 seems to yield consistently accurate results. Is this something that makes any sense to you?

Comment: It's hard to tell, since you don't provide any data. As I said, pick simple test data set (let's say 4 figures; each 3-4 points). Write them down. Run algorithm. Use temporary variable for `localPointsArea`. Print it out and write it down. And see what's the result after scaling. And publish the numbers here. Or make a Gist on GitHub with the code and pass a link. In order to help, I'd have to be able to run what you have in my head, but the way you present it,  I can't do it -- I don't have enough data.

Comment: Here is some test data. I am drawing these coordinates on the screen: (317.5, 280),
(733.5, 280),
(733.5, 634),
(317.5, 634),

This results in a rectangle with width 416 points and height 354 points. The area calculated by hand, as well as by my area function based on gauss area calculation is 147264 points^2. The scale on my device is 2.0, and the dpi is 264. This would result in the calculation (147264 * 2^2) / (264^2) which equals 8.45179 in^2. The physical measurements I have made with a ruler are ~ 3.5 x 4 = 14 in^2.

Comment: One interesting thing I am noticing while writing this is that the width and height in points seem to correlate to the width and height in inches by a factor of 100. This results in the area in points^2 being approximate to the area by a factor of 10,000. 14.76 inches^2 is within ~5% of what I measured off the cuff, and is what I would consider an accurate estimation of the area. The 8.45179 result I am getting from my formula is ~77% off from this value, which is what I am consistently seeing with multiple data sets. Do you see what is causing this deficit? is 1/100 factor a coincidence?

Comment: I'm seeing the same. On my iPhone 6s `1in` = ~115points, while on iPad Pro 1in is around 95 points.

Comment: Very interesting. I have seen people publish points per inch values a few places, but normally they are between 153-163/inch. I wonder why we are seeing something different? I have also noticed through further testing that the area calculation in my above post seems to yield the correct result, if the image I am drawing above to compare measurements to is larger or equal to resolution of the device. If the image has a lower resolution I seem to get that moving discrepancy factor when I compare measurements on device to physical measurements on paper.

Comment: The image I am drawing over is displayed at full size with no scaling, so I would think the measurements would always line up. I need to run more tests, but using a low resolution image to measure against may have been the cause of the entire problem (not that I don't need to solve that issue still, but I think I am at least getting closer).